# How to print an inverted triangle, sorted right?

Tags: python, for-loop

```
***
 **
  *
```

This is what I'm trying to get python to print.
The conditions are the following:
**1. must use nested loops or more.**

I've solved this with the following code:

```
n = 0
for i in range(3,0,-1):
    print(" "*n ,end = "")
    n+=1
    for j in range(0,i):
        print("*", end="")
    print()
```

However, I'm trying to see if I can get the same output **without declaring the 'n' variable**.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `n == i - 3`, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantage of str.rjust() like this:

```
WIDTH = 3

stars = '*' * WIDTH

print('\n'.join(stars[i:].rjust(WIDTH) for i in range(WIDTH)))
```

**Output:**

```
***
 **
  *
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this with the following:

```
for i in range(3): 
  for j in range(i):
   print(' ', end = '')
  for j in range(3-i): 
    print('*', end='')
  print()
```

Comment: Nested loops are unnecessary. The `*` operator works with strings, which is used in the other answers. For example, `"*" * 3` is `"***"`, and `" " * 0` is `""`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def printTriangle(columns:int):
    return "".join([" "*space+"*"*(columns-space)+"\n" for space in range(1+columns)])
    
print(printTriangle(5))

>>> *****
>>>  ****
>>>   ***
>>>    **
>>>     *
```